# serialize attribute without value in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

I am working on a WCF service and our team wants to be able to serialize a valueless attribute form the contract. for example the xml would look like this:

```
<Payload>
  <Options all></Options>
</Payload>
```

as you can see **all** is passed as an attribute, only when the user wants all the options. the value all will not be provided if all is not provided.

This would be how the request for all options would be sumitted, vs a request for specific options

```
<Payload>
  <OptionList>
    <Option>option 1</Option>
    <Option>option 2</Option>
  </OptionList>
</Payload>
```

I currently have a Option data contract as follows:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName="Option", Name="OptionList", Namespace="")]
public class OptionListV1:List<string>, IExtensibleDataObject
{
    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

I know there is the XmlSerializerFormat attribute, but I am having a hard time determining if I can serialize a valueless attribute with the XmlSerializer.

Any ideas?

**TL;DR:** I want to serialize/deserialize a boolean property as a valueless attribute.

**update** if you believe this is a duplicate question, please answer the question with a link to the existing question.

Comment: You can't, since every attribute must have a value http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: so the disabled or attribute in html is an extension of xml? I thought HTML was still considered valid xml.

Comment: `html != xhtml` No, every html is not a valid xml.

Comment: good to know. just looked this up. guess HTML is a child of SGML, not XML. Glad to have learned something new today!

Comment: why did you mark this as a duplicate? I searched for an hour to find if anyone one else had asked. If this is a duplicate, please link said duplicate question.

Comment: Nathan, refresh your page and see the top of your question.

Comment: well I am an idiot! didn't realize they added that link area!